# Find the remainder when $3^{101}$ is divided by $10$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Find the remainder when $3^{101}$ is divided by $10$

Ans: $3$

My approach 1: Remainder theorem

When i apply remainder theorem I solve like $3$^$2$ . $50$+$1$/$3^2$-$(-1)$=$3$($-1)^{50}$=-$3$/$10$=$3$   @Edit

Approach2: Pattern method:

$3^4$ . $25$ + $1$=$3^\frac{1}{10}$=$3$

I am getting different answers through both approaches.

What is my mistake in †he first method and which to prefer while solving problems?

Comment: I updated your latex, can you please see that is it correct?

Comment: @JeelShah Yes its correct Thanku I will keep in mind next time.

Comment: I think you're making it way more complicated than it needs to be. If you look at the first ten powers of 3 or so, the pattern should be much more obvious: 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, 3, 9, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** : $3^2 = -1 $ (mod $10$).Hence what can you say about $3^{100}$  ?

**Edit:** By above observation ,$3^{100}=(3^2)^{50} =1$ (mod10).Hence what can you say about $3^{101}$ ?

Comment: i have not got your hint.

Comment: Dear @justintakro,I've edited the post to make it more clear!